# Are there human general communication languages without a future tendency?

Tags: chinese, japanese, tense, thai

In Thai language there is no *past tense*, at least not for negative sentences:

- A Thai person might say "I don't go" (`ฉัน ไม่ ไป`) while the listener is expected to guess from the context if it means past (`I did not go`) or present (`I don't go`)
- A *present marker* such as `กำลัง` or `อยู่` could be utilized to emphasize if something doesn't or does happen presently, but it won't necessarily be used

In contrast, Thai language **does have** a *past marker* as "already" (`แล้ว`) for positive sentences such as "I go (went) already" (`ฉัน ไป แล้ว`).

---

That said about past; it is interesting to note that Thai language does have a future tense as with "I will not go" (`ฉัน จะ ไม่ ไป`) or as with "I will go" (`ฉัน จะ ไป`).

---

All of this brought me to wonder if there are human general communication languages without a future tense and if not, how can it be explained that all languages include present and future tenses but at least one lacks past tenses?

Comment: When you say "tendency" are you referring to what is more commonly called [habitual aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_aspect)?

Comment: Many languages including Japanese and Finnish don't mark the future tense in any way on the verb, so your statement “all languages include present and future tendencies” is wrong. Besides, “tendency” doesn't seem to be a generally accepted grammar term. Those แล้ว and จะ are tense-aspect-mood markers.

Comment: In my opinion, the "Thai" tag is inappropriate for this question since it isn't really asking about the Thai language.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am not a native speaker of English nor ever studied linguistics formally, it's very hard for me to understand what is the term you referred to so all I can say now is "maybe" and anyway I meant to what reflects "I will" in English.

Comment: @variableism Do you mean a future **tense**? What linguists call a tense is something different from how lay people use the term, but in the looser sense (how most people learn it at school), English has both a ‘future tense’ and a ‘past tense’. According to Wikipedia, Thai (like Chinese) doesn’t have any tenses, and the exact same phrase can be past, present or future depending on context, which seems to be the opposite of what you say in your question. But I don’t know Thai, so I can’t guess what makes your (untransliterated) examples future…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks, I should edit the untransliterated examples and yes, I think I meant "tense" instead "tendency".

Comment: While the past is in memory and the present is going on now, the future is entirely supposition and fantasy. We don't know what's going to happen next, though we try hard. Even languages with paradigmatic future tense marking have lots of ways to refer to the future; and future tenses tend to change rapidly as new expressions get popular.

Answer (score 2):

Many languages have a distinction between *past* and *non-past* that doesn't explicitly mark the future. Japanese, for example:

- 食べます *tabemasu* "eat, eats, will eat"
- 食べました *tabemasita* "ate"

English sometimes does the same thing:

> After I **finish** this report, I'll come to the meeting.

The "finishing" is clearly in the future, but there's no explicit marking of that. In Latin, on the other hand, an explicitly future form would be used here (*fēcerō* "I will have finished").